# Not able to get the cell data of Java tree - UFT

Tags: hp-uft

When I am using `getcelldata` method for Java tree object, nothing is being returned.

```
Celldata=javawindow("Oracle").javatable("Console").getcelldata(1,1)

Celldata=javawindow("Oracle").javatable("Console").getcelldata("#1","#1")
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you actually wrote it with a space before `getcelldata`?

Comment: @victor - there is no space...

Comment: The syntax of the first line seems correct to me. Is your code properly identifying `javawindow("Oracle").javatable("Console")`? Have you tried to execute `JavaWindow("Oracle").JavaTable("Console").Highlight` and see if the table is properly highlighted?

Comment: Able to highlight the javatable and able to select particulat cell also. Issue is while retrieving the cell data.

Comment: That's odd and unfortunately I don't have access to UFT anymore, so I won't be very helpful. Sorry abou that. Let's hope for someone to shed a light here.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few possible reasons for this

1) You are not using the correct row and column numbers for fetching the data. Row and column starts with 0. So if you want to fetch the data for row 1 and column 1 then your statement should be

GetCellData 0,0 not 1,1

To check if you are on the right row and column you can use ActivateCell or ClickCell functions. Both of these function indexes starts with 0, so they should match.

2) Check if there are any child controls inside the table cell, sometimes that will cause issues getting the data from the cell, because if cell is having a custom control inside it then cell technically does not have the data.

To check this use the childObjects function

3) If GetCellData is not working, then you can also check, if you are able to add the table cell directly in the object repository and get the text using GetROProperty.

4) If nothing else works then you can also check the native functions and properties.

To access the native properties and function you can use object spy.